# How to invoke save as prompt for returned filepath

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I haven't really coded this before but I've got a list of file names in my view.  There's a download button next to them.  So for example:

[image]

here's the view markup for that:

```
@foreach (CarFileContent fileContent in ModelCarFiles)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("GetFileDownloadUrl", "Car", FormMethod.Get, new { carId = Model.CarId, userId = Model.UserId, @fileCdnUrl = fileContent.CdnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("userId", Model.UserId);
        @Html.Hidden("carId", Model.CarId);
        @Html.Hidden("fileCdnUrl", fileContent.CdnUrl);        
        <p><input type="submit" name="SubmitCommand" value="download" /> @fileContent.Name</p>
    }
}
```

When clicked, I send over the CdN url to my action method which under the hood goes and downloads that file from Rackspace and then copies it to our server for the user to download.  So my action method returns back the url to the .zip file that the user has now access to download.  But when I test this, it's posting back and redirecting me to a blank page that shows the url rendered in text on the page and that's it!

```
"http://www.ourAssetServer.com/assets/20120331002728.zip"
```

I'm not sure how to invoke a save as prompt instead and keep the user on the same View they are already in or redirect them back to the same view that lists out the files to download...

What I want to happen is this:

1. User clicks on the download button
2. Action Method does its thing, downloads the file in the backend
3. User seemlessly gets a save as pop-up immediately after clicking the download button

this is probably routine but I've never done this before.  I need help figuring out how to get the save as prompt to show up and how I should handle returning to my View after my action method gets the final download url for the .zip...what do I do with that url in my action method...return it to the view?  Not sure here.

here's the action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetFileDownloadUrl(string fileCdnUrl int carId, int userId)
{
    string downloadUrl = string.Empty;
    downloadUrl = GetFileZipDownloadUrl(carId, userId, fileCdnUrl);

    return downloadUrl;
}
```

**downloadUrl** returned in my action method is that "*http://www.ourAssetServer.com/assets/20120331002728.zip*" string for example sent back to the user...I just need to figure out how to get this wired up to a save as prompt but also figure out how to handle the view...do I redirect back to the same view or what?
**UPDATE:**

After researching a bit more, here's what I came up with:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FilePathResult GetFileDownloadUrl(string fileCdnUrl, int carId, int userId)
    {
        string downloadUrl = string.Empty;
        downloadUrl = rackSpaceTask.GetFileZipDownloadUrl(carId, userId, fileCdnUrl);
        int i = downloadUrl.LastIndexOf("/");

        string fileName = downloadUrl.Substring(i);

        return File(downloadUrl, "application/zip", fileName);
    }
```

I get the error `'http://ourAssetServer.com/assets/20120331002728.zip'; is not a valid virtual path`

**UPDATE #2**

Here's my latest attempt using the redirect method to try and get a save prompt to show.  What's happening is it is hitting my GetFileDownloadUrl but then never seems to get to my Redirect action method and I end up being redirected to a completely blank page (all white) with the url as http://localhost/Car/GetFileDownloadUrl and just stops there

```
    @foreach (CarContent fileContent in Model.CarFiles)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("GetFileDownloadUrl", "Car", FormMethod.Post, new { carId = Model.CarId, userId = Model.UserId, @fileCdnUrl = fileContent.FileCdnUrl }))
        {
            @Html.Hidden("userId", Model.UserId);
            @Html.Hidden("carId", Model.CarId);
            @Html.Hidden("fileCdnUrl", fileContent.FileCdnUrl);        
            <p><input type="submit" name="SubmitCommand" value="download" /> @fileContent.Name</p>
        }
    }


public void GetFileDownloadUrl(string fileCdnUrl, int carId, int userId)
{
    string cownloadUrl = string.Empty;
    cownloadUrl = GetFileDownloadUrl(carId, userId, fileCdnUrl);

    RedirectToAction("RedirectToUrl", downloadUrl);
}


public ActionResult RedirectToUrl(string fileUrl)
{
    Response.Redirect(fileUrl);
    return null;
}
```

I'm not sure how the RedirectToUrl should be coded...the return type and what do you return if anything?  Should it just redirect keeping me on the page I was on?  I don't "think" this is even being hit, only my first method.  I put a debug point on the Response.Redirect and it's never hit..only a debug point on RedirectToAction("RedirectToUrl", downloadUrl);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider defining a new action "RedirectToUrl" that takes url as parameter and then using RedirectToAction in your code:

```
public ActionResult GetFileDownloadUrl(string fileCdnPath int carId, int userId)
{
    string downloadUrl = string.Empty;
    downloadUrl = GetFileZipDownloadUrl(carId, userId, fileCdnPath);

    return RedirectToAction("RedirectToUrl",
        new { url = downloadUrl });
}
```

Update: using the FilePathResult with Server.MapPath is another option (assuming that the server you're downloading the file to is the same as server running your ASP.NET MVC code). Add the following to the bottom of function in your last edit:

```
 var assetsPath = Server.MapPath("~/assets");
 var localPath = Path.Combine(assetsPath, zipFileName );

 return this.File(localPath, "application/zip");
```

Comment: This will allow you to redirect your user to the file url (i.e. http://ourAssetServer.com/assets/20120331002728.zip) which will, in turn, cause the browser to open up Save As dialog etc depending on browser's settings. That would only work if the server (ourAssetServer.com) is accessible by the client.

Comment: what would RedirectToUrl be, an action method? And what would that do inside?

Comment: So the action method RedirectToUrl would return void and do a Response.Redirect to that url?  And then I wouldn't need an action result as the return value on my GetFileDownloadUrl?

Comment: Yes, RedirectToUrl would be a controller method which simply does return Redirect(url);

Comment: yea did that but it did not do anything..no prompt to save

Comment: That means that redirection part didn't work for some reason, can you update your question with new code?

Comment: I will update with my latest code in the post.  But what should my redirecttourl action method return?

Comment: also you'd think it should be a GET but only POST is working in terms of hitting that initial controller action

Comment: also, why create a whole new Action Method, and not just do the Response.Redirect at the end of my first action method?

Comment: actually my latest post is working, I had a config issue of where the file was being download.  So what should that redirecttourl return for the Action method RedirectToUrl?  after it redirects do I return null or what?  I feel like the server is not tying up loose ends if it just redirects and doesn't really close the controller instance?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a `FileResult` instead of a `string`.

```
return File(path + fileName, "application/zip", "20120331002728.zip");
```

Comment: Just tried that after researching a bit...but then I get http ://www.ourAssetServer.com/assets/20120331002728.zip is not a valid virtual path.

Comment: one problem is probably that I don't have a path, I have a url to the file.  I should be able to use a url somehow I'd assume...

Comment: I thought you were downloading the file locally? The path should be local to the web application.

Comment: cant use this, I don't have a virtual filepath, only a url.

Comment: it's not local, we're using a url to our cdn server to get the downloaded file